# Exclude a dependency from Renovate updates

Tags: dependency-management, renovate

I use Renovate to keep my dependencies up-to-date. However there are some dependencies that I want to exclude from automatic updates, i.e. I don't want Renovate to update them, ever.

One such dependency is Postgres, which is specified in `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
```

Currently, Renovate is creating PRs that would change the 11 to 15. Is there a configuration option in Renovate that allows me to exclude this dependency from Renovate?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a [package-rules](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules).

This rule will disable updates for all dependencies found in docker compose files which have `postgres` in their name.

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["postgres"],
      "matchManagers": ["docker-compose"],
      "enabled": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `ignoreDeps` in renovate.json e.g.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "schedule": ["before 7am on the first day of the month"],
  "ignoreDeps": ["postgres"],
  "rangeStrategy": "update-lockfile",
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "description": "Group minor and patch dependency updates",
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["*"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch"],
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "groupSlug": "all-minor-patch"
    }
  ]
}
```